# How do I properly connect to a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    require_once('config.php');
    $link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) or die ('Your DB connection is misconfigured. Enter the correct values and try again.');
?>
```

I have stored my host, username, password and database name in the separate file config.php. I know that the information is correct because I can connect to my database via putty, but I keep getting the error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'blank'@'T9AF3.WPA.blank.Ca' (using password: YES) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\temp2\index.php on line 3 Your DB connection is
>   misconfigured. Enter the correct values and try again.

Note: 'blank' is there to protect my identity and is not a typing error.

Edit: I only used putty to test that my login information was correct. Putty has very little to do with my actual question.

Edit2:

```
<?php
    $db_host = 'host';
    $db_user = 'user';                  
    $db_pass = 'pass';                  
    $db_name = 'dbname';
?>
```

These are filers.

Comment: can connect to my database via putty ??? you mean via command line ?

Comment: No I think you misunderstand. I just copy and pasted this error statement and the first blank is to replace my username and the second blank states my university. I am not showing them on here, but in my code they are correct.

Comment: how do you connect from putty ?

Comment: Don't use your custom error, but `if (mysqli_connect_error()) { die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());}`  This way you know the REAL mysql connection error.  THen we can answer your question.  And other people, please STOP guessing.

Comment: Please update your question with the contents of the config file related to the DB. obviously you should substitute the actual username and password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can login from putty, by that i think you mean localhost, and you can't from php file, which is i think trying to connect remotely, the problem most probably lies on your user not defined for your servers ip. your server, which you are trying to connect from is 'T9AF3.WPA.blank.Ca' 
in mysql a username has a password and a location and mysql uses both to authenticate the user. you can have permission to connect locally but not remotely i.e. from another server. check with your system admin to make sure you have proper access defined from 'T9AF3.WPA.blank.Ca'.

Or you have not specified an IP Address for the server to listen to. It may only be listening on localhost of your server, instead of allowing remote connections. Check your mysql configuration and which IP address it is listening on.

Comment: I am doing this for a class I am taking. I don't understand why I wouldn't have the proper rights to log into the database remotely. I say this because the professor has not come forward with this problem. He also told us that we should be testing on xamp, wamp or mamp.

Comment: Sorry a little new to this. How would I check this?

Comment: are you able to run php scripts from putty locally? if yes try uploading your script to the same server with the database and try if it connects.

Comment: I have yet to try this on putty. I am not actually using putty to connect. I only used it in the beginning to test if I could login to the mysql server.

Comment: if you could login with same username/password on same server with database, then the problem is definitely your user being not allowed to access remotely.

Comment: Oh really? Is this something that is fixable on my own or would I have to speak to a person who can change my permissions?

Comment: if you have the admin privileges for the database you could, but i doubt it. so you'll have to ask your professor.

Comment: he might be asking you to develop in that server not on your own.

Comment: I'll have to think on that.I may have not found a solution, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Your mysql user must have proper rights on the database you are using